# Dimension Member as Measure in MDX

Tags: mdx

I need to get a dimension member returned as a measure.

Given:

Dimensions

```
[Customer].[customer name] members {ACME, EMCA, EMC}    

[Salesperson].[person name] members {Bob, Fred, Mary, Joe} with the property "name"
```

Measures
Value

Relationships

```
The Customer is a dimension of the facts that contain Value
The Salesperson is a dimensions of the facts that contain Value, each customer has one salesperson associated
```

I am trying to do the following:

Create measures that will return the name of the salesperson in a column for a customer. e.g.

```
| Customer          |Sales person | Value |
| ACME              | Bob         | 500   |
| EMCA              | Bob         | 540   |
| EMC               | Mary        | 840   |
```

I have tried like this:

With Member [measure].[sp_name] as [Salesperson].[person name].currentmember.properties("name")

Select 
{[measure].[sp_name], [measures].[value]} on 0
{[customer].[customer name].members} on 1
from

But it always returned error "properties name is not valid for [Salesperson].[all salesperson]"
And if I used `With Member [measure].[sp_name] as [Salesperson].[person name].currentmember.firstindex.properties("name")`
I got one person for all the customers, which is obviously not right. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in Analysis Services 2008, this should work as you implemented it, returning `null` for the `All` member. If the environment that you use is more sensitive, then maybe you could use something like

```
With Member [measure].[sp_name] as
     IIF([Salesperson].[person name].currentmember IS [Salesperson].[all salesperson],
         'All',
         [Salesperson].[person name].properties("name")
        )
Select {[measure].[sp_name], [measures].[value]} on 0,
       {[customer].[customer name].members} on 1
  from [MyCube]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Salesperson].[person name].CurrentMember.Member_Name
```